# Limit maximum time of query execution for a particular group in redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a [group of users](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Groups.html) in Redshift. I would like to limit the maximum time of their query execution to some particular value.

Something similar to [statement_timeout](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_statement_timeout.html), but no one would need to write `set statement_timeout to 1000;` before each session, and no one can overwrite this value.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via WLM queues. A specific group of users can be assigned to a queue and given a [WLM timeout](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-defining-query-queues.html#wlm-timeout).

FWIW, I've not found WLM (WorkLoad Management) to be worth the added complexity and potentially idle resource.

Comment: When you told about groups, did you mean these [groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Groups.html)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. :)